# Arrangement of letters of BLACKI

Tags: combinatorics

Letters of $BLACKI$ are arranged in order such that $B$ is not at $1$st, $A$ is not at $3$rd and $K$ is not $5$th. In how many ways can this be done?

Comment: A real life solution: Python code `len(list(l for l in itertools.permutations('blacki') if l[0] != 'b' and l[2] != 'a' and l[4] != 'k'))` returns 426.

Answer (score 1):

[Use the inclusion–exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):
Let $X$ be the the set of all arrangements of those letters. Then $|X|=\_$
$A_1$ is the set of all such arrangments with $B$ as the first letter. Then $|A_1|=\_$
$A_2$ is the set of all such arrangments with $A$ as the third letter. Then $|A_2|=\_$
$A_3$ is the set of all such arrangments with $K$ as the fifth letter. Then $|A_3|=\_$
You are looking for 
$$\begin{align*}&|X\setminus(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)|\\
=&|X|-(|A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|)+(|A_1\cap A_2|+|A_1\cap A_3|+|A_2\cap A_3|)-|A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @Sherlock Watson: Fill in the blanks

Comment: Yes, I surely will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b$ be the number of ways with $B$ 1st, $a$ the number of ways with $A$ 3rd, $k$ the number of ways with $K$ 5th. Similarly let $ba$ be the numer with both $b$ 1st and $A$ 3rd, and so on. Then what you want is to take the total arrangements $t$ and compute
$t-b-a-k+ba+bk+ak-bak$. This uses "inclusion exclusion" which you should be able to look up or google.